# Replace OAuthUri with OAuthAuthenticator

Tags: .net, google-oauth

I have the folowing:

```
Uri retUri = null; 

if (this.settings.OAuthUser != null && 
    location.IndexOf(OAuthUri.OAuthParameter) != 0)
{
    //
    // How to replace in the following line 
    // the OAuthUri with OAuthAuthenticator ?
    //
    retUri = new OAuthUri(location, this.settings.OAuthUser, 
                          this.settings.OAuthDomain);
}
else 
{
    retUri = new Uri(location);
}
```

The warning says :

> Warning   196 'Google.GData.Client.OAuthUri' is obsolete: 'this is going
>   to be removed in the future and replaced with OAuthAuthenticator'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an older version of the Google client lib

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis
```

The Oauth code will look something like this

```
UserCredential credential; 
 credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
              new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "YourClientId", ClientSecret = "YourClientSecret" },
              new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
              "user",
              CancellationToken.None,
              new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result; }
```

Scopes will change depending upon which API you are trying to connect to.  Also FileDatastore stores the refresh token in %AppData%, if you want to store it someplace else you will need to make your own implementation of Idatastore.

There is a short tutorial on it here [Google Oauth2 C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/)